# How to display stackexchange data on my site?

Tags: php, apache, authentication, dataexplorer

**Introduction**
<sub>I am developing my presentation site and I want to include my Stack Overflow profile info/posts/data (eg top tag, score and so on.)</sub>

I found data.stackexchange.com to retrieve the desired data but I can't understand how can I show this data in my site.
In github.com I found this prerequisites: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer#prerequisites which basically says that I must be a **.NET programmer** to be able to display this data but I am a **PHP programmer**, I work with `Apache` `MySQL` and `PHP`.

I know that there are lots of [PHP MsSQL functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) I can use but how can I connect to the Stack Exchange database (I think as a guest/limited user) with which username-password?

Even if this is not too much on-topic here, where can I find more info on how I can display Stack Overflow data on my site?

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/3492/wordpress-widget-to-display-a-stack-overflow-profile) wordpress widget

Comment: Thank you @beresfordt for your response but I can't/want use wordpress, is there something I can use with pure PHP?

Comment: Did you even check the wordpress widget recommended by @beresfordt, wordpress is also in PHP and as you mentioned in question you work with PHP so it's not very hard to understand how wordpress widget is working and with little bit effort you can make it standalone plugin to work with your presentation site.

Comment: @Shehary indeed, exactly why I mentioned it

Comment: @theTaskmaster - I don't know why you voted on my answers so repeatedly but you have caused me some problems with moderators, please read [the rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) and don't do it again, I just want to give my answers, not being targeted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if CONFUS3D' answer is a good solution, any alteration to the User Interface may cause errors in your site.

I suggest you to use the [Stack Exchange API set](http://api.stackexchange.com) with which you can retrieve the most of data you probably need.

Any API query will return a **JSON object**. I use this PHP class to retrieve this object:

```
class ApiReader {
    public function getResponse($url) {
        $cH = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($cH, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($cH, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($cH, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($cH, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($cH, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, cURL);
        curl_setopt($cH, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($cH, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

        $result = curl_exec($cH);

        if(curl_errno($cH)) {
            $retur = FALSE;
            }
        else {
            $status = curl_getinfo($cH, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            if($status == 200) {
                $retur = $result;
                }
             else {
                 $retur = FALSE;
                 }
             }
         curl_close($cH);
         return $retur;
         }
     }
```

I use this little trick to test the site even if I am off-line.

In your host, save all the JSON objects you need to use, then declare two vars `$UInfo_API` containing the API query and `$UInfo_Syn` which gets the content of the saved JSON object

```
$UInfo_API = "api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/5039442?site=stackoverflow";
$UInfo_Syn = file_get_contents("yourjsonobject.json");
```

Then save the result in a variable checking if the `getResponse()` method has failed or not. After that, you have the data on tap.

```
$sear = new ApiReader();
$uInfo = $sear->getResponse($UInfo_API);
$uInfo = ($uInfo !== FALSE)? json_decode($uInfo, TRUE): json_decode($UInfo_Syn, TRUE);
$rep = $uInfo["items"][0]["reputation"];
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend checking out http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Something like this should get **reputation** using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

```
$html = file_get_html('https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039442/thetaskmaster');
$reputation = $html->find('.reputation', 0)->plaintext;
```